# Clearing a list using a for loop

Tags: c#

I'm making a Black Jack game, and at the start of every new round I need to clear the list of cards that represents the Player's and the Dealer's hands. I used this to do so:

```
public void ClearPlayerHand()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < PlayerHand.Count; ++i) 
            {
                PlayerHand.Remove(PlayerHand[i]);
            }
        }
```

Problem is I always seem to be left with one card left in the list, or I receive an out of bounds error, no matter how I change the value of i, what is the best method of removing all the elements from the PlayerHand?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your collection `PlayerHand` implements [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) you can just call the `.Clear()` method.

A common implementation of this interface is [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

If you do want to clear a `List<T>` via a `for` loop, you should use a reverse `for` loop. The reason for this is that as you remove an item from the list, it will shift all the index's down one, and you could easy run into index out of bounds exceptions.

An example of this would be:

```
        for (int i = PlayerHand.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            PlayerHand.RemoveAt(i);
        }
```

Comment: Indeed, and if it doesn't, it probably *should*.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are right: use `Clear`.

But, if you *wanted* to do this with a loop and `Remove` calls, here's how you would do it:

```
for(int i = PlayerHand.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  PlayerHand.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Reversing the direction of the iteration is the real trick.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best/easiest way to do it.

```
PlayerHand.Clear();
```

**Reason for out of bounds**

As for why you are receiving the out of bounds exception, it's happening because you're removing elements from the list but continually counting up. You would want the last operation to remove `i = 0` but it keeps counting.

Say PlayerHand has 3 items in it, the following occurs:

```
i = 0
remove PlayerHand[0] (it now contains 2 elements)
i = 1
remove PlayerHand[1] (it now contains 1 element)
i = 2
remove PlayerHand[2] (this throws an exception as only PlayerHand[0] exists)
```

Normally you would count backwards in this case:

```
for (int i = PlayerHand.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another suggested approach beside `Clear` method, you can also use `RemoveAll` to either remove all or part of list

```
// Remove all items
PlayerHand.RemoveAll(x => true);

// Remove part of list
PlayerHand.RemoveAll(x => ConditionMethod(x));
```

Comment: Why would anyone prefer this to `Clear`?

Comment: @CodyGray: Just another option

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can consider using data binding and then you should update the ItemSource, instead of directly manipulating the listbox or listview items.

```
List<T> SomeSource=...
PlayHand.ItemSource=SomeSource;
SomeSource.Clear();
```